# Proof verification regarding Cyclic Groups and Groups containing Unique Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

I am trying to prove the following theorem below, but with my own method. I have hit a stumbling block and am curious if there is a way around it.

**Theorem**: Let $G$ be a finite group. Then $G$ is cyclic if and only if for every positive divisor $d$ of $|G|$, there exists a unique subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $|H|=d$.

I can do the forwards direction. For the backwards, I first wrote
$$|G|=p_1^{e_1}\cdot \cdots \cdot p_m^{e_m}.$$
From here I was able to show that there exist elements $g_i\in G$ of order $p_i^{e_i}$ for every $i$ and that every element of order $p_i^{e_i}$ is contained in a single group. Since we don't know (yet) $G$ is abelian, I cannot argue with a previous result that $\prod_{i=1}^{m}g_i$ will have order $|G|$. Any suggestions where to go from here or should I scrap this?

Comment: If $H$ is the unique subgroup of order $d$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup, so every subgroup is normal. This isn't enough to prove $G$ is cyclic (it's not even enough to prove $G$ is abelian) but maybe it will come in handy.

Comment: As the previous comment remarks, every subgroup is normal. In general, if $H, K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ that intersect trivially, they commute. You have (cyclic) subgroups of order $p_i^{e_i}$, and they intersect pairwise trivially because they have coprime order. So you can conclude as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the backwards direction, let $s=|G|$, $p_1^{e_1}\cdot \cdots \cdot p_m^{e_m}$ be the prime factorization of $s$, and $H_d$ denote the subgroup of $G$ of size $d$. One of my previous results implies that for each $i$, $H_{p_i^{e_i}}$ is cyclic (normal in $G$). Furthermore, since these groups are normal with relatively prime sizes, it follows that $H_{p_i^{e_i}}\cap H_{p_j^{e_j}}$ is trivial if and only if $i\neq j$. Thus, for each $i$ and $j$, the elements of $H_{p_i^{e_i}}$ and $H_{p_j^{e_j}}$ commute. Now for each $i$, set $g_i\in H_{p_i^{e_i}}$ to be an element of order $p_i^{e_i}$. Since the elements $g_1,\dots,g_m$ commute with each other, it follows that
$$\prod_{i=1}^{m}g_i$$
will have order $p_1^{e_1}\cdot \cdots \cdot p_m^{e_m}=s$.

Here I am using the fact that if $x$ and $y$ commute and if $\text{ord}(x)=s$ and $\text{ord}(y)=t$, then $\text{ord}(xy)=\text{lcm}(s,t)$.

Comment: To elaborate on Gerry Myerson's comment, we know $H_d$ will be normal because the map $x\to gxg^{-1}$ is an automorphism, so the image of $H_d$ will also be size $d$.  By uniqueness, this must be $H_d$, so $H_d$ is normal.